# ARC do not free memory allocated for private variables

Tags: objective-c, ios5, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, private-members

In one of my view controller I have defined an private variable as follow,

```
@implementation CNLibraryViewController {
 CNMaterialsViewController *_materials;
}
```

Every time when I reload the view, I newly allocate memory and initialize this variable as follow,

```
_materials = [[CNMaterialsViewController alloc] init];
_materials.gridViewActionDelegate = self;
_materials.itemRetrieving = self.dataModel.itemRetrieval;
[_materials setSortDescriptors:_sortDescriptors];
[_materials loadItems:[results allObjects]];
```

In the `CNMaterialsViewController.m`I have defined some private variables as follow,

```
@implementation CNMaterialsViewController {
    CNItemViewController *_itemViewController;
    id<CNItemViewControllerViewSetupDelegate> _itemDescriptionTileSetup;
}
```

So the problem is, the retain count of these two variables increase one by one for the every `CNMaterialsViewController` initialization.

Could not find any reason for that. Can any one help me to find out the problem.

As a solution, I assign to `nil` those variables before initialize `CNMaterialsViewController`. But I do not feel that as a good solution.

So, please help me.

Comment: Try to implement it with properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the compiler a cue as to how you want ARC to treat ivars. If you don't qualify the variable as `__weak` the compiler will assume you want a strong reference and will hold on to it as long as its parent is still around.

Adding to what @mariusLAN said, you don't need to declare ivars anymore--you can simply declare a property and state your intentions there. i.e.

```
@interface CNLibraryViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) CNMaterialsViewController *_materials;
@end
```

Comment: I tried with the property implementation. But still the # Living of the _materials instance is increasing. :(